# Неоднородные определения — всегда ли без запятых?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить запятые, если имеется четыре неоднородных определения (как в этом случае)?

**Возле дома стоял рыжий усатый гигантский суровый охранник.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Между несколькими определениями могут быть различные отношения: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Чаще встречает **не более трех** неоднородных определений, так как большее количество определений сложно прочитать в одну фразу (без перечислительной интонации). Если определений больше, то желательно сблизить значения некоторых из них.

Например, в заданном предложении можно выделить два однородных определения с описанием внешности: *Возле дома стоял **рыжий, усатый гигантский суровый** охранник.*

Но лучше выбрать такой вариант (тогда получается как бы три определения):  *Возле дома стоял **рыжий и усатый гигантский суровый охранник**.* Здесь раскрыты две темы: яркие детали внешности и суровый вид.

В любом случае **подбор определений** должен соответствовать художественной задаче и при этом обеспечивать удобное прочтение фразы.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не говорила столь категорично, что все прилагательные, перечисленные вами, — неоднородные.

1. Думаю, что *рыжий* и *усатый* как раз таки однородны (описывают внешность).
   Это подтверждают [В. Дмитриева](https://books.google.ee/books?id=EPxxAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=M67LAg3Pct&sig=ACfU3U0dYvVOOBUOHnQ1XGesNUJOGuCBQg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbtYrtsOvhAhXw0aYKHUFXAvAQ6AEwF3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0&f=false) (между ними стоит запятая) и [К. Чуковский](http://textbook.keldysh.ru/tarakan/text.htm) (стоит союз **и**).

> **Рыжий, усатый,**
>   Как зебра, полосатый,
>   Как лев, зубастый —
>   Не кошка — зверь опасный!
>
> ---
>
> Вдруг из подворотни
>   Страшный великан,
>   **Рыжий и усатый**
>   Та-ра-кан!

2. [Суровый](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/5251/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) охранник — вряд ли здесь имеется в виду характер человека, скорее — *суровый на вид* или *с суровым выражением лица.* А это ведь тоже "показатели" внешности.
3. Я бы написала так (и для восприятия, думаю, лучше, и голова не сломается).
   **Возле дома стоял гигантский суровый охранник, рыжий и усатый.**

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/234-odnorodny)